# Flutter BlocProvider throwing an error while returning Future

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-bloc

I am trying to return a Future inside my BlocProvider and it is throwing an

**Error: Inferred type argument 'Future' doesn't conform to the bound 'StateStreamableSource<Object?>' of the type variable 'T' on 'BlocProvider'**

```
class SignInScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const SignInScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: BlocProvider(
        lazy: false,
        create: (context) => getIt.getAsync<SignInFormBloc>(),
        child: SignInForm(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `create` callback should return valid `StateStreamableSource` object (most common type is `Bloc` / `Cubit`) and not `Future`

Comment: @pskink Thanks for replying. However, SignInFormBloc is registered as an  Async Factory. Any idea how to use it then?

Comment: by wrapping with `FutureBuilder` maybe?